# How to search in MySQL in a 60G table containing 330M rows?

Tags: php, mysql, bigdata

I have a table which is 60G and has about 330M entries.

I must display this on a front-end web-app. On the web-app there is a search function which searches a string pattern in every row of the database table.

The problem is that this search takes up to 10 min and makes the MySQL process freeze. I looked for solutions but haven't found a suitable one.

- In-Memory Database: database is too big (it goes up to 200 GB - 60GB is only at the moment)
- Split up the table into a table for each month a put these on 6 SSDs (I need the data from half a year) then it's possible to search parallel on 6 SSD
- reduce the data amount (?)

Image is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2TyD.png

Comment: Some indexes and the right queries should do the trick, I have a table with over a few billion records.

Comment: Difficult to make suggestions about this without at least seeing the table structure

Comment: the index file will be 20 GB isn't that also a problem with the performance, for the query i took WHERE "message" LIKE "searchpattern"

Comment: `searches a string pattern` - you mean you're using a REGEXP or LIKE search?

Comment: But if you use LIKE, the database engine can't use indexes....consider switching to [FULL TEXT INDEXING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html)

Comment: @MarkBaker That's not entirely true, the part before the first wildcard uses indexes.

Comment: as in the picture of the table ... when you search after imap-login, the query is WHERE "message" LIKE "imap-login"

Comment: I take it that `LIKE` expression has a `%` at the end?

Comment: @halfer no when I search after something its just that pattern, without wildcards * or %

Comment: Isn't a `LIKE` without any wildcards the same as an equality comparison (`=`)? It looks like the `msg` column has more to it than just `imap-login`, etc.

Comment: yes msg column has a lot of different entries ... i just took 3 rows, that you can see the structure of the table ... but do = and LIKE has a performance difference ?

Comment: I would imagine they are different in performance terms, but why not try it? It's a very quick change. I take it you have an index on this column? I suspect you _will_ need the wildcard anyway, since presently you are doing an equality test when you actually want "begins with".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an implicit cursor to search threw the db You could consider closing it after say every 50 rows then reopening it at the row you stopped it at.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of **database sharding** here. It basically splits up your big database into several small databases.
Here's a quick link for you :- http://codefutures.com/database-sharding/